# "keep printed documents" re-enabling itself

Tags: print-server, queue

We have Windows Server 2016 as a print server with roughly 40 printers of various makes (Ricoh, HP, Konica), most of which are deployed via GPO.  A few months ago the 'jobs in queue' started filling up after jobs are printed.  We disable the 'Keep printed documents' option and clear the queues and they operate correctly until the workday is over.  The next morning they all automatically re-enable the 'Keep printed documents' option on their own and the queues start filling up again.  I have searched any can not find much information or anyone else with the same problem, except for one article about a single stand-alone Brother printer, which needs to be set to 'RAW', but it doesn't apply here.  We have PrintAudit and PaperCut Print Logger monitoring our usage, but we've tried uninstalling both to see if it continues and it still keeps happening.  Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like these settings are coming back from gpo-connected printers. do NOT gpo conected printers show the same behaviour?

Comment: Only the printers that are in 'Print Management' on our print server and deployed to all of our domain PCs are doing this.  We have other network printers that are stand-alone and only installed for certain users and they do not appear to be building any jobs in queue.

Comment: That is where i'd start researching. I bet there is a flag in that GPO somewhere, restoring this unwanted setting. I am very sorry that I can't be more helpful.

Comment: I do appreciate your help.  I had already checked the GPO for any settings like this, and there aren't any.  The GPO is just the 'Deployed Printers' under Computer > Policies > Windows settings.  It doesn't allow any settings or anything, just deployment.

Comment: `It doesn't allow any settings or anything` is not really ow gpo's work ...